# How to refresh database data only in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

So I want to copy just the data from a Prod database (SQL 2005) down to my local machine (SQL 2005 & SQL 2008 Management Studio installed).

The problem is I'm running into foreign key constraints that are causing the task/scripts to fail. I can get by these errors if I import certain tables first, but is there an easier way to do this all at once? I'm not a DBA so I don't have access to the database back up.

I've tried the SQL Import/Export data Wizard and Publishing Wizard, but it also gets the PK error.

Comment: Also does anyone know if there is a 64 bit version of sql management studio (non-express)? Even with SQL 2008 R2 it installs Management studio in the x86 folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would drop all Foreign Key contraints, the re-apply after you have copied all the data across.

e.g.

```
-- Drop Constraint

 IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.foreign_keys WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].   [FK_ForeignKeyName]') AND parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[Table]'))
 ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Table] DROP CONSTRAINT [FK_ForeignKeyName]


-- Add it back again
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Table]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_ForeignKeyName] FOREIGN KEY([FeildName])
REFERENCES [dbo].[OtherTable] ([OtherField])
```

Answer (score 1):

Details on how to globally disable/enable constraints in order to do bulk data importing:

http://decipherinfosys.wordpress.com/2008/02/20/disableenable-foreign-key-and-check-constraints-in-sql-server/